# Is there a way to equalize all the colors' brightness in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, color, brightness, saturation

I want to know if there's a way to equalize the **brightness** of **all the colors** of an image. Like, I have a color image, I want to make its all colors' brightnesses the same value.

Ex -

- H-43 S-73 B-101  → H-43 S-73 B-101
- H-122 S-81 B-201 → H-122 S-81 B-101
- H-122 S-91 B-192 → H-122 S-91 B-101
- H-131 S-73 B-85  → H-131 S-73 B-101

  Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a graphic design question. Not a photography-related one.

Comment: @Rafael It's also applicable to processing photos.

Comment: Yes. Almost every graphic design process can be applied to photos. But this is not a photography question.

Comment: One need not use a graphic design application at all to do this. Any raw image processing application with an HSL/HSV/HSB tool should suffice.

Comment: What is the *photographic* purpose for you to "want to make its all colors' brightnesses the same value"? Many photo editing tools separate luminance and color as a means to an end, not the end in itself.

Answer (score 3):

You need a program that can handle HSB channels.

Separate the image into HSB channels

[image]

Fill the B channel with the value you need and recombine.

[image]

You will get a weird image.

This process is very destructive, mainly because the H channel needs more than 255 levels, let's say 360 at least.

And by flattening the B channel you are destroying the main source of information.

I did this on PhotoPaint, PhotoShop does not use HSB channels, so you could try using Lab channels.

<sub>https://pixabay.com/es/photos/azul-gafas-de-sol-mujer-piscina-2705642/</sub>

Comment: HSB (Hue + Saturation + Brightness) is alternatively known as HSL (L for Luminance) or HSV (V for Value) in some image processing applications.

Comment: HSL is a different color mode. But if your application has not HSB, probably will not have HSL either.

Comment: Value is max(R,G,B), while Luminance is a weighted combination of the three.

Comment: I use several applications with (only) HSL that do the exact same thing as other applications with (only) HSV or (only) HSB.

Comment: @Rafael this can be achieved in Photoshop by changing the image mode to "Lab" and applying the luminosity value to the "Lightness" channel.  Works very similar to HSL.

Comment: @Rafael - ugh, sorry - I've only just noticed your last comment